# In a logistic regression with two fixed effects how should I decide which random slope to include?

Tags: regression, logistic, random-effects-model

I am running a logistic regression with two fixed effects.

I am including random subject and item intercepts.

I am not including random item slopes because my items can only belong to one level of the fixed effects.

A model with random subject slopes for each of the fixed effects fails to converge. Models with only one random subject slope, for either of the fixed effects, do converge.

How should I go about deciding which of the two subject slopes to include?

Comment: Do you mean with "random subject slopes" a predictor serving as a random effect?

Comment: Hey Pat, yes I do.